# How to format a cell header in xlsx angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How to format a cell in angular using xlsx or the cellStyles.

here's the code.

***list.component.ts***

```
const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(reportData);
          ws['!cols'] = [];
          Object.keys(reportData[0]).forEach((cell: any) => {
            const colWidth =
              cell === 'Date'
                ? 120
                : cell === 'Time'
                  ? 100
                  : cell === 'Location'
                    ? 200
                    : cell === 'Temperature'
                      ? 80
                      : cell === 'Humidity'
                        ? 80
                        : 100;
            ws['!cols'].push({
              wpx: colWidth
            });
          });

          XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, this.roomTitle);
          XLSX.writeFile(
            wb,
            `${fileName}.xlsx`,
            { cellStyles: true },
          );
```

what I'm trying to do here is to format it into `BOLD TEXT` the header which is the `Date, Time, Location, Temperature and Humidity`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try following?

```
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True});
```

As per documentation you have to add in format.

```
 write(row, column, token, [format])
```

which will be like,

```
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total', bold)
```

Comment: what's the value of row?

Comment: @ABC Kindly refer this - https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial02.html